# Cannot compile C program in Visual studio code

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I am getting this results in the terminal.

gcc.exe: error in visual studio code.

How to fix this?

I was working well until now, don't know what happened.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add spaces to the name of your C/C++ files, you will then need to let the compiler know that this is a single file, this can be achived by using quotation marks around the file name:

```
gcc "If condition.c"
```

That said, it's not the best idea to have C/C++ files with spaces, you shouldn't do it.

Suggestion: rename `If condition.c` as `If-condition.c` or `If_condition.c`

Comment: But using spaces or tabs inside C source code file names is a *disgusting* and *shameful* habit (hostile to [glob(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html) on Linux and POSIX systems)